# How to add leading constraint to the right edge of the UILabel in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout

How can I achieve the equivalent of this in storyboard?

```
[cell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nameLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:cell.contentView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:200.0]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily, in storyboard, control click on view and drag to the other view. Then click settings of the constraints on the right:

[image]

and click on **Select and edit** which will take you to constraints settings:

[image]

Comment: Great, so I changed the constraint from leading to trailing on the label in the inspector and it works. Thank you!

Comment: No prob, glad I helped.